# How to config gerrit refs in Zsh?

Tags: bash, zsh

In my team, we use gerrit for code review.

As you know, gerrit uses the magical 'refs/for/*'.

---

Since I do not want to type

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/*
```

every time I push to remote,

I tried to change my git repository's config like below.

```
git config remote.origin.push refs/heads/*:refs/for/*
```

---

Changing config works well in bash,

but it fails in my zsh with an error like below.

```
zsh: no matches found: refs/heads/*:refs/for/*
```

I think that using an asterisk in zsh is somewhat different with bash,

but I cannot know exactly what the problem is.

---

How can I solve this problem? or impossible in zsh?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Be aware that `refs/heads/*:refs/for/*` pushes *all* local branches. This might not be what you want.

Comment: @michas Yep, I know it! Thank you for reminding me anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default when bash fails to glob it puts the whole pattern into the arguments unchanged. When zsh fails to glob it does not run command at all which I find more convenient in most cases. Both shells can be configured, zsh has at least three other modes: do like bash, remove pattern from arguments and remove pattern from arguments unless there are no patterns with match. These behaviors are achieved by unsetting `NOMATCH` or setting `CSH_NULL_GLOB` or `NULL_GLOB` respectively.

I would suggest keeping current behavior and using various escaping methods: `'refs/heads/*:refs/for/*'` (double quotes also work) or `refs/heads/\*:refs/for/\*`.